# Error: operator does not exist: bit = integer

Tags: postgresql, variables, bit, assign

I need to assign value 1 to variable which is of type bit.

**Example**:

```
create or replace function test()
returns void as
$Body$
Declare
       var1 bit :=0;
Begin
       ....
       ....
       var1 := 1;
       ....
       ....
end;
$Body$
language plpgsql;
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: bit = integer
```

Comment: can you put whole function because I check with this code and it run successfully in postgreSQL 9.2

Comment: @IleshPatel, Yeah! I got it from following answer. Thank you Ilesh for your quick response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [bit string literal](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-bit.html) like this: `var1 := B'1'`. Here some more [examples](http://www.java2s.com/Code/PostgreSQL/Data-Type/UsingBitdatatype.htm) on bit type.